# How to encode long and multilingual personal names in RDF?

Tags: rdf, ontology, foaf

For example, full Jobs name is

`Steven Paul "Steve" Jobs`

while Queen singer was

`Freddie Mercury` with born name of `Farrokh Bulsara`.

Elton John is `Sir Elton Hercules John` and born `Reginald Kenneth Dwight`.

How to store all this with RDF? What about same name in different languages? Is [FOAF dictionary](http://xmlns.com/foaf/spec/) enough for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a lot of different questions folded into one. Let's start with Steve Jobs. How you write this down depends on the granularity with which you want this data available. Whichever way you want it though, the [FOAF vocabulary](http://xmlns.com/foaf/spec/) is expressive enough. The simplest/least fine-grained way is just to stick the entire name in the `foaf:name` property:

```
:steveJ a foaf:Person ;
        foaf:name "Steven Paul \"Steve\" Jobs" .
```

However, FOAF also offers a couple of more specific name-properties to further break this down. For example:

```
:steveJ a foaf:Person ;
        foaf:givenName "Steven Paul";
        foaf:familyName "Jobs" ;
        foaf:nick "Steve" .
```

A handy combination is to have whatever you prefer to be the 'default name' encoded as an `rdfs:label`, which is what most RDF consuming applications will initially use to display a resource. For example like so:

```
:steveJ a foaf:Person ;
        rdfs:label "Steve Jobs";
        foaf:name "Steven Paul \"Steve\" Jobs";
        foaf:givenName "Steven Paul";
        foaf:familyName "Jobs" ;
        foaf:nick "Steve" .
```

So as an author of this data you have enough expressivity in FOAF vocabulary to break this down however you see fit - or even to offer redundant alternatives, like you see above.

Now as for Freddie Mercury, Elton John and their birth names, FOAF does not offer a specific property for that. You can of course just record it as a second value of the `foaf:name` property, but that makes it hard to distinguish which name is the 'current' one. If that distinction is important you will need to use something else for this. DBPedia offers the `dbo:birthName` property which is very specific for this case, or the more general `dbo:alias`.

Finally, different languages: this is fairly straightforward. RDF literals carry an (optional) language tag that specifies the language in which a name is written. Let's take a city name as an example (since it's easier for me to come up with different names in different languages) - the Dutch city of The Hague:

```
:TheHague rdfs:label "The Hague"@en ; // English name
          rdfs:label "Den Haag"@nl ;  // Dutch name
          rdfs:label "La Haye"@fr .   // French name
```

Comment: There are more cases in general. For example, in Russian, there are 3 fixed components of name: name, patronymic and surname. Is there any property for patronymic in FOAF? Also, in English, there are more complex cases, like Bill Gates, who is `William Henry "Bill" Gates III`. Can I tag "number" separately with FOAF?

Comment: Right, those weren't in your original question of course. Looking at them I don't think FOAF has standard properties for those cases, so you either generalize to fit with one of the standard properties, or you just extend,  introducing your own properties (or reuse another existing vocab, I remember something like that existing, will add link if I find it)